# how to call class from pone class to another class

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone. what i am doing is creating two classes named as classone,classtwo. now what i need is i have to call calsstwo from classone. I already import classtwo in classone. pls post some code thank u.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Init an object of type `Classtwo` in `Classone` and send it messages from there. You should probably head for some basic Objective-C stuff first: http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html